# Swift4 Json Parse Alamofire Set Struct

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, codable

I have a jsonArray data like that:

```
[
     {
       "data1":"data1",
       "data2":"data2",
       "data3":"data3",

       },
       {
       "data1":"data1",
       "data2":"data2",
       "data3":[
              {
              "data1":"data1",
              "daya2":"data2"
              }]          
   }
]
```

Data3 may be a string or String array like above. My struct is:

```
  struct Datas: Decodable{
        let data1: String?
        let data2: String?
        let data3: String?
      }
```

There is no problem when data3 is string, but I get an error when data3 is array 
**"Expected to decode String but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil)**)

I cant solve that. What is the type of Data3? Any object does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json swift4 how to set the struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782706/json-swift4-how-to-set-the-struct)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `AnyObject` you'll probably want to use the `Any` type instead. Then use an `if let` to cast to either and array or string. You could also consider use the very helpful [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library to help with processing JSON objects.